# DDD accessing reference values in Domain layer without repositories

Tags: domain-driven-design, repository

So I have built a domain model and some logic into that. I have created two repositories for two aggregate roots.

My question is *how to access to the reference data from these layers?*. For example, say we have the following types `Elder` and `Young`.

Our application entry points expect `Elder` or `Young` as inputs. But, to validate and save this in the database (*which has a foreign key to another table `PERSON_TYPE` which has these 2 values*), I need to convert these IDs to store aggregate roots.

Could I create a `PersonTypeRepository` (in the domain layer) and use it when I persist my aggregate roots? Should this conversion happen in domain layer or should it happen in the application layer? For example, from a service

***Edit***: For now I have gone with this approach. From `controller` I call `Assembler` for the `DTO`. I created a non-domain model repository (*Infrastructure* layer). Then from `Assembler` I build the domain model (caveat is exposing `setMethods()` of a domain model) using the `Autowired` `Repository`

Comment: @Laiv can you please explain?

Comment: Why design an entry point that accepts one of two values? Does the _caller_ to your entry point not know which type is being passed? "Garbage in, garbage out."

Answer (score 1):

If you have three seperate tables, then creating three **Domain Models(Entity Model)** and **repositories** is common way. Then, manage business and transaction scope on **Service Layer(Application Layer)**.

If it looks hard to create individual repository for each table, then you can use **Generic Repository Pattern**. This generic repository lets you use common method for each Domain Model.

**Note :** You can also use **Unit of Work** instead of using these 3 separate repositories but it is not shown from here.

```cs
    public interface IGenericRepository<T> where T : class 
    {
        T Get(int id);
        int Create(T model);
        int Update(T model);
        void Delete(T model);
        List<T> GetAll();
    }

    public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        private readonly IDbContext _dbContext;

        public GenericRepository(IDbContext dbContext)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext;
        }

        // implementations
    }

    public class SomeService
    {
        private readonly IGenericRepository<Young> _youngRepository;
        private readonly IGenericRepository<Elder> _elderRepository;
        private readonly IGenericRepository<PersonType> _personTypeRepository;

        public SomeService(IGenericRepository<Young> youngRepository,
                           IGenericRepository<Elder> elderRepository,
                           IGenericRepository<PersonType> personTypeRepository)
        {
            _youngRepository = youngRepository;
            _elderRepository = elderRepository;
            _personTypeRepository = personTypeRepository;
        }


        // this method parameters can be changed and this personTypeId 
        // can be into elder or young instance.
        public void SomeMethod(Elder elder, Young young, int personTypeId)
        {
            PersonType personType = _personTypeRepository.Get(personTypeId);

            // some validations here.

            // your business requirements
            try
            {
                // using(begin transaction here by your dbcontext)
                // getting dbconext can change by your design.

                _youngRepository.Create(young);
                _elderRepository.Update(elder);

                // commit transaction.

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // rollback here
                throw ex;
            }

        }
    }
```